# How can I create Oracle SQL with specific Order by?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

This is my initial data pattern 
[image]

I would to order data in Value column ascendingly but reserve its original groups like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT part, "group", value
FROM tablename
ORDER BY "group", value;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I don't know about oracle that's why didn't put anything - could you please give some references

Comment: You can go to docs.oracle.com , choose database > Oracle Database > category Topics: Development  > SQL Language Reference (HTML or PDF)> 19 MERGE to UPDATE > SELECT. On the top of the page you can find "SQL Queries and Subqueries", in which also "Sorting query results" is available. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SQL-Queries-and-Subqueries.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, why `"group" ` only and what its referring to ? is it by mistake because the exact query wont work

Comment: I know why you did but it will only work if the column name is given like `"group"` during the table creation which is not clear from OP's question and it could be an alias ? or am i missing something ?